# How to use ported library in NaCl module?

Tags: c++, c, native-code, google-nativeclient

I want to use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org) library in my NaCl module. Luckily it is ported already as in https://code.google.com/p/naclports/. However, its kind of pity but I don't know how to add the library to the toolchain. I did as instructed in the `Readme` file:

> ...nacl_sdk/pepper_33/naclports/src$ python build_tools/naclports.py install openssl
>   Already installed 'openssl' [x86_64/newlib]

And then I tried to compile this simple C [code](http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt), and the compiler complaint some errors which are because of linking problem with `openssl/evp.h`.

This is my Makefile: [link](http://codeshare.io/ijkUl). Please let me know how to make it run.

Answer (score 2):

NaCl actually consists of several different toolchains.   naclports will build and install a given library to just one of them at time.   The libraries and headers get installed directly into the toolchain so there is no need to -L or -I on the command line.

In this case you have built and installed the x86_64 newlib version of openssl.   This means that you should be able to build the x86_64 newlib version of your app (add TOOLCHAIN=newlib NACL_ARCH=x86_64 to your make call).

To build all the other versions of openssh you can use the "make_all.sh" script at the top level of naclports (e.g. ./make_all.sh openssl).

Answer (score 1):

Build naclports. Look in naclports/README.rst for instructions.