# Can I make calls to APIs such as youtube-dl and ffmpeg from a chrome-app?

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, google-chrome-app, youtube-dl

First of all, I haven't started the implementation of the system I'm about to describe, as I didn't want to commit on implementing something I did not know if was possible.

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to build a chrome-app to download the audio from certain websites (e.g. youtube and soundcloud) using youtube-dl, post process it using ffmpeg and then upload it to a cloud service via some api. The reason I want to do it via a chrome-app is because I could do all the work on the client side (no need for servers) and I'd have the ability to insert javascript into the pages using content scripts, which would make the app pretty simple to use (I could create buttons such as 'download song' and stuff like that).

Although I have already read the documentation explaining the NaCl Technical Overview and some of the Application Structure, I still am not sure as to whether I would be able to make these calls via some C/C++ module or if I would get denied due to security reasons.

To summarize: considering that the user has the needed dependencies in his system (youtube-dl, python, ffmpeg and etc.), is it possible to make calls to third party APIs such as the ones described before via a chrome-app using NaCl ?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Regarding "didn't want to commit on implementing something I did not know if was possible": I encounter this problem frequently, so what I do is develop a quick prototype whose only purpose is to test out the questionable approach. That's much safer than any answer on SO when it comes to avoiding wasteful development spending on a doomed design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome apps are normally sandboxed.

Less so than extensions - they can reach much more system resources via app APIs.

But still, what you mention is *executing* libraries / utilities out of browser, and it's not normally allowed.

(P)NaCl is tightly sandboxed in this regard. See [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920954/google-chrome-extension-using-nacl-with-an-external-library), it still applies: you can only use 3rd-party code that compiles into NaCl along with your app, not just link to a library. There are some library ports to NaCl, but it's not automatic.

Normally, a few years back you would use a mechanism like NPAPI to reach out and use a library out of browser. It's deprecated, and won't work anymore. In its place, Chrome offers a pipe-like (through stdio) connection to an external program called [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging). You could use it to perform operations with system-level libraries and tools, but the downside is that you can't bundle the native host with your app, you'll need a separate installer.

Comment: Thank you for the information Xan. I imagined i'd run into a security-related problem with this design.. Regarding the idea of using Native Messaging, the reason I wanted to build the app using NaCl was to hopefully bundle it all together, but as it seems it can't be done like I wanted, I guess I'll just return to my first design (using a web service to receive the information from the chrome extension).